# TypeError: result.data.umdHub.articles.forEach is not a function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am having issues linking pages with slugs. All I am aiming to do is create a page with a list of articles (which I have). But I cannot link those articles to display their content. I understand you might need to use createPages. Below is the code I am trying. Does anyone have experience with this that might be able to point me in the right direction for linking index and article pages?

```
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  // **Note:** The graphql function call returns a Promise
  // see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise for more info
  const { createPage } = actions
  return graphql(`
      {
        umdHub {
          articles {
            data {
              slug
              title
              body
              subtitle
              hero_image {
                url_1200_630
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  `
).then(result => {
    result.data.umdHub.articles.forEach(({ data }) => {
      createPage({
        path: articles.data.slug,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/article.js`),
        context: {
          // Data passed to context is available
          // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
          slug: articles.data.slug,
        },
      })
    })
  })
}
```

I am getting this error with the above code:

> TypeError: result.data.umdHub.articles.forEach is not a function

---

**Second Attempt:**

```
const path = require(`path`)

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const articleTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/terp/article.js`)
  // Query for markdown nodes to use in creating pages.
  // You can query for whatever data you want to create pages for e.g.
  // products, portfolio items, landing pages, etc.
  return graphql(`
    {
        umdHub {
          articles {
            data {
              id
              title
              subtitle
              body
              summary
              hero_image {
                url_1200_630
              }
              authorship_date {
                formatted_short
                unix
                unix_int
                formatted_long
                formatted_short
                time
              }
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
  `).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      throw result.errors
    }

    // Create blog post pages.
    result.data.umdHub.articles.data.forEach(data => {
      createPage({
        // Path for this page — required
        path: `${data.slug}`,
        component: articleTemplate,
        context: {
          // Add optional context data to be inserted
          // as props into the page component..
          //
          // The context data can also be used as
          // arguments to the page GraphQL query.
          //
          // The page "path" is always available as a GraphQL
          // argument.
        },
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Returns error:

> ⠐ createPages Your site's "gatsby-node.js" created a page with a
>   component that doesn't exist

Comment: may be ` result.data.umdHub.articles` is not an array.

Comment: based on the error message I'd say `result.data.umdHub.articles` is definitely not an array. Have you tried your graphql query in `localhost:8000/___graphql`?

Comment: Ah I see its not, in graphql data is the array. Still not sure where to go after finding this out

Comment: the new error message says the path to your article template is wrong, could you check?

Comment: This question has been evolving. I asked another question with more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871899/graphql-request-error-unknown-argument-slug