# GraphQL request error - Unknown argument 'slug'

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to link my index.js page to an article template to display the data from a middleware Drupal site using a slug and `createPages`. I have the data displaying correctly on my index.js page and my `createPages` seems to not have any errors after changing the file path to `./src/templates/article.js`.

I am running into this GraphQL error while compiling:

> error GraphQL Error There was an error while compiling your site's
>   GraphQL queries.   Error: RelayParser: Encountered 1 error(s):
>   - Unknown argument 'slug'. Source: document `usersBrooksrelytHtdocsRepositoryGatsbyGraphqlGatsbySrcTemplatesArticleJs4119530598`
>   file: `GraphQL request`
>
> ```
>   GraphQL request (3:12)
>   2:   query($slug: String!) {
>   3:     umdHub(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
>                 ^
>   4:       articles {
> ```

My article.js code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'reactstrap';

// eslint-disable-next-line
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Header from "../components/header"
import Footer from "../components/footer"


export default ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div className="container spaces article">
        <div className="row">
          <section className="col-md-9">
            <div className="tag-list">
              <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/">Highlighted</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/">Innovation</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/">Web Only</a></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">February 28, 2019</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <h1>{data.title}</h1>
            {data.hero_image.map((hero, i) => (
              <div key={i}>
                <img className="img-fluid no-pad-top med-spaces" src={hero.url_1200_630} alt=" " />
              </div>
            ))}
            <div className="row article-content">
              <div className="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                <h2 className="subheader">{data.subtitle}</h2>
                <div className="author"> 
                  <p>By <a href="/">Jane Doe</a> | Photos by <a href="/">ISTOCK</a></p>
                  <hr />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <aside className="col-md-3">
            <div>
              <ListGroup flush>
                <ListGroupItem disabled tag="a" href="#">Recent Posts</ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem tag="a" href="#">Dapibus ac facilisis in</ListGroupItem>
                <span>February 27, 2019</span>
                <ListGroupItem tag="a" href="#">Morbi leo risus</ListGroupItem>
                <span>February 27, 2019</span>
                <ListGroupItem tag="a" href="#">Porta ac consectetur ac</ListGroupItem>
                <span>February 27, 2019</span>
                <ListGroupItem tag="a" href="#">Vestibulum at eros</ListGroupItem>
                <span>February 27, 2019</span>
              </ListGroup>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </div>


      <Footer />
    </div>

  )
}


export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    umdHub(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      articles {
        data {
          id
          title
          subtitle
          body
          summary
          hero_image {
            url_1200_630
          }
          authorship_date {
            formatted_short
            unix
            unix_int
            formatted_long
            formatted_short
            time
          }
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

My gatsby-node.js:

```
const path = require(`path`)

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const articleTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/article.js`)
  return graphql(`
    {
        umdHub {
          articles {
            data {
              id
              title
              subtitle
              body
              summary
              hero_image {
                url_1200_630
              }
              authorship_date {
                formatted_short
                unix
                unix_int
                formatted_long
                formatted_short
                time
              }
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
  `).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      throw result.errors
    }

    result.data.umdHub.articles.data.forEach(data => {
      createPage({
        path: `${data.slug}`,
        component: articleTemplate,
        context: {

        },
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Hope useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55930667/8585114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut for `filter` only works on field of immediate node, i.e you may filter `umdHub` by `articles`. So when you filter by slug, it looks for field `slug` in `umdHub`, which doesn't exist because slug is under `umdHub.articles.data` instead.

This might help:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {

-   umdHub(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
+   umdHub(articles: { data: { slug: { eq: $slug } } }) {

      articles {
        data {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Still getting the error on 'articles' in `umdHub(articles: { data: { slug: { eq: $slug } } }) {`

Comment: @brooksrelyt what error are you getting for articles?

Comment: `error GraphQL Error There was an error while compiling your site's GraphQL queries.
  Error: RelayParser: Encountered 1 error(s):
- Unknown argument 'articles'. Source: document `usersBrooksrelytHtdocsRepositoryGatsbyGraphqlGatsbySrcTemplatesArticleJs1360934319` file: `GraphQL request`

  GraphQL request (3:12)
  2:   query($slug: String!) {
  3:     umdHub(articles: { data: { slug: { eq: $slug } } }) {
                ^
  4:       articles {`

Comment: @brooksrelyt it looks like `umdHub` doesn't support filter & search. How did you create `umdHub`, or which cms / plugin created it for you?

Comment: @brooksrelyt it looks like my answer got awarded the bounty even though it didn't solve your problem. Ping me the next time you run into a difficult problem & I will add a bounty there for you!

Comment: You have answered more than one of my questions and have gotten me out of a few confusing situations. I owe you. I have learned a lot about querying even if it hasn’t helped this specific issue. I learned that it is not working because an outside development agency created their own GraphQL iteration, that they even said doesn’t work well with gatsby. I was emailed this on Tuesday

Comment: @brooksrelyt I'm glad my answers were helpful & you have figured out the problems. Good luck with your project!