# normal graphql queries causing errors

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have been searching around for a while and been getting a lot of help from the SO community. But, it seems that the setup of my project isn't allowing normal queries such as sort, limit, filter, or others.

I am querying a custom middleware/drupal site.

Examples that throw errors:

```
{
  umdHub(limit: 5) {
    articles {
      data {
        id
        title
        subtitle
        body
        summary
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  umdHub(
    sort: {
      fields: [authorship_date___time]
      order: ASC
    }
  ) {
    articles {
      data {
        id
        title
        subtitle
        body
        summary
        authorship_date {
          formatted_short
          unix
          unix_int
          formatted_long
          formatted_short
          time
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All return errors in http://localhost:8000/___graphql like:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown argument \"limit\" on field \"umdHub\" of type \"Query\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I resolve these issues?

Comment: Can you post your resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was the way to do it:

```
{
  umdHub {
    articles (page: { limit: 5 }) {
      data {
        id
        title
        subtitle
        body
        summary
        hero_image {
          url_1200_630
        }
        authorship_date {
          formatted_short
          unix
          unix_int
          formatted_long
          formatted_short
          time
        }
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That because you don't have argument `limit` in on field `umdHub`. 
To resolve, let's check your schema, on the `umdHub` field of type `Query`, and add `limit` arguments, then restart your server.

Exemple:

```
type Query {
  umdHub(limit: Int, sort: SortInput) { // <-- Add this
   articles
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, there was some documentation I was not aware of. Slightly different implementation I posted above, not sure it helps anyone else but your answer might